# Catalan divided by increasing powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the value of the converging sum $\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{2}{k^3}+\frac{5}{k^4}+\frac{14}{k^5}+\frac{42}{k^6}+\frac{132}{k^7}...$,  where the numerators are the catalan numbers in sequence. Assume that $k \ge 4$.

I tried to use the recursion form, but it becomes extremely messy. 
I also tried to find a short recursion to find the value to make it similar to the problem with the fibonacci #s instead of the catalan #s instead, but I can't seem to find such a recursion. Lastly, telescoping sums seem to not work, since it is hard to express each term as a difference of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the generating function of the Catalan sequence will give the answer. Check it out here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: thank you very much! I got it! Is there a clever way to solve it, though, without using generating functions?

Comment: By the way, is it just a coincidence that the catalan sequence provides that nice simplification when squared? Or are many sequences solved by this method?

Comment: @TheMathTroll: The recurrence for the Catalan suggested a square.  For many important sequences the generating function is known. Perhaps a peek at generating functions?